# Publishing ASP.NET Core to Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core-2.1

Just letting you know that I'm new in Linux and have been trying for a while now to publish a ASP.NET Core website on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

I have developed a test project in ASP.NET Core 2.1 in Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to publish it on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have followed the following steps described in this article:

https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/07/publishing-and-running-your-asp-net-core-project-on-linux/

Instead of publishing the test website described in the article I want to publish my own website. I'm publishing the website in Visual Studio 2017.

After publishing the website to the working directory on Linux I have the following files:

- Docker.DotNet.dll
- TestCoreWebsite1.deps.json
- TestCoreWebsite1.dll
- TestCoreWebsite1.pdb
- TestCoreWebsite1.runtimeconfig.json
- TestCoreWebsite1.Views.dll
- TestCoreWebsite1.Views.pdb
- web.config

When I type in the command in Linux terminal "journalctl -xe" I get the following error:

```
realpath(): Permission denied
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/var/www/.dotnet' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOpt
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
at Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.FileWrapper.CreateEmptyFile(String path)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSentinel.Create()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel nugetCacheSentinel, IFirstTimeUseNot
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
tcore.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
tcore.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It tells me that "/var/www/.dotnet" is denied. In actual fact is that this path doesn't even exists.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Strange by following the steps of this article it still doesn't work.

```
leo@leo-virtual-machine:/var/www$ dotnet  --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.401
 Commit:    91b1c13032

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.3
  Commit:  124038c13e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.401 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0-preview1-002111-00 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
leo@leo-virtual-machine:/var/www$ dotnet  --version
2.1.401
```

Is there a problem because I have multiple versions off .NET Core runtimes installed?

Comment: See the first 2 lines. Try to adapt the permissions of the /var/www/.dotnet folder.

Comment: Hi, /var/www/.dotnet folder doesn't exist. What do you mean with adapt the permissions if the folder doesn't exists?

Comment: @Leo as per the instructions the cmd "journalctl -xe" that you execute to cause the errorw allows you to check logging on the Apache startup sequence, journalctl -xe has nothing to do with .NET has nothing do with a .dotnet folder and you have not even created a dotnet application as the instructions your are following with the command dotnet new mvc

Comment: @Leo there is no way you are getting the error you are getting from "When I type in the command in Linux terminal "journalctl -xe" I get the following error"

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm not sure what you mean. I have created an asp dotnet core application and I have the dlls in the directory "/home/leo/websites/testcore".  I know that the "journalctl -xe" has nothing to do with the .NET. I'm sorry that my writing has confused you. I was just trying to tell what I was doing to display this error. I knew that it was something to do with Apache. But how does your answer help with the question that I have?

Comment: Why is Apache having a problem with this path "/var/www/.dotnet"? My application isn't in this directory and I have not referenced anything to this directory. Or does Apache expect me to have my website in the "/var/www/.dotnet" directory?

Comment: Hi @Brian. Just to let you know. I have not followed the command "dotnet new mvc" in this article because I want to see if I can develop asp  dotnet core application on my laptop with Visual Studio 2017 and publish it to this linux Ubuntu server.

Comment: I've cautch this same error on my centOS configuring one of my dotnet core apps, after a long time chasing it I've discovered that in the systemd service I've reference the dotnet core app dll with the name in different case, leading and that leads the start process to break things and throw this same error. 

My app dll was named ITCheckIn.dll and in my systemd service it was referenced as /var/www/html/app/itcheckin.dll

Comment: Thank you @DiegoGarcia for sharing this.

Comment: Google pointed me here, and @DiegoGarcia pointed me to my problem <3 Should create an answer out of it and mark it as the best one, if it also helped OP :)